# Modifying interactive python script to accept argument at start

Tags: python, encryption

I'm hoping to decrypt a bitwarden file that belongs to me (lost password), using this [script](https://github.com/GurpreetKang/BitwardenDecrypt). I have a CSV dictionary of possible passwords. I have tested the password with a similar file and I can run it manually in the windows command line.

I would like to use BitwardenDecrypt as part of another script with this workflow:

```
+reads a potential password from csv file

+calls BitwardenDecrypt with potential password

+checks exit code

+if not 0, try next potential password
```

My biggest challenge is modifying BitwardenDecrypt to accept an argument. I have taken a look at the script on GitHub and I don't quite understand where I would start.

Comment: Simple way is to use sys.argv

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing

Answer (score 0):

I had good luck using autohotkey and programming a script that ran in the windows command line. This approach allowed me to open my own vault by testing about 10k combinations. Thanks for everyone's help.